# PHPMyAdmin larger upload limit not changing

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have changed these values using SSH on my server:

```
post_max_size = 50M

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 50M
```

I have restarted both `httpd` and `mysqld` services and restarted the whole server, but when looking at `phpinfo();` it still shows:

```
upload_max_filesize 2M  2M
```

I cannot upload larger files in PHPMyAdmin

I edited `php.ini` in `/etc/` directory

Comment: there are several `php.ini` files, which one do you edit exactly? `phpinfo()` will show you the right one in line `Loaded Configuration File`

Comment: are you sure you have saved the file after editing? It is not possible to save the file if you dont have administrator/root privilages

Answer (score 0):

Did you opened php.ini and checked whether the values are changed or not? sometime in lamp you need root access to change configuration.

Simple way is to use htaccess file to change these values.

Add these in your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value post_max_size 900M
    php_value upload_max_filesize 640M
    php_value memory_limit 600000M
    php_value max_execution_time 2592000000000
    php_value max_input_time 25920000000000000
    php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 120000000
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.htaccess` file and simply put below code in it and give it a go. Please make sure to upload this file on the root of the website.

Code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine On

    php_value  upload_max_filesize  1000M 
    php_value  max_input_time 160
    php_value  upload_max_filesize 100M
    php_value  post_max_size 100M 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Why need to enable `RewriteEngine` and changing `Options`? Also, is not `php_value` from `mod_php5.c`module?